# Trouble with for loop and promise, as I need to iterate through object to get values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array called `previewMessages`, and I need to loop through an object `messages`, and get a bunch of values. One of these values requires an async call, and of course this won't work if I want to use the `previewMessages` variable after the for loop, e.g. to sort it.

Here's the code:

```
var displayMessages = function(messages) {
    let previewMessages = [];
    for (let messageID in messages) {
        let message = messages[messageID];
        let messageObj = {};

        Promise.resolve(getItemsById([message.context.itemID])).then(function(itemInfo) {
            messageObj.title = itemInfo[Object.keys(itemInfo)[0]].title;
        });

        previewMessages.push(messageObj);
    }
}
```

I can't do `promise.all` because messages needs to be iterated through, and I need an async call to get the title.

if this helps, here's the first function, that calls the above function:

```
var getUserMessages = function(id) {
    usersRef.child(`${id}/chats/`).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        displayMessages(snapshot.val());
    })
}
```

Comment: *"I can't do promise.all because messages needs to be iterated through, and I need an async call to get the title."* That doesn't follow. Is there a reason the async calls can't be running in parallel?

Comment: Yes, because func1 returns an object of say 100 messages. func2 then iterates through each item that func1 returned, and uses a value from a key for each message to do another async call, to push to that outside array. I can't think of a way to get this working >_>

Comment: @VDog that's exactly where you'd use `Promise.all(func1).then(func2)`. If you show us those functions in your actual code, we might be able to advise you

Comment: @Bergi so the problem isn't getting the data from func1 into func2, the problem is that func2 takes the return object from func1, and has to iterate through each key in the object, get a value from that key, call an async function to get the value's title, and then append this to an array.

Comment: @VDog: That's fine, the link from `func1` to `func2` can be in a chain, and those chains can be in parallel. But since you didn't show us that, I wasn't able to take it into account in my answer.

Comment: @VDog Then simply use another `Promise.all` inside `func2` to return a promise for the array

Comment: Yeah I got it, I didn't know I can do that with promises, I thought promise.all() just took multiple async calls, completed them on their own accord, and when they are done you can use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives for you:

If the async calls can run in parallel (even though there could be 100 of them, it doesn't matter), you *can* use `Promise.all`:

```
let previewMessages = [];
let promises = [];

// Build the array of promises
for (let messageID in messages) {
    let message = messages[messageID];
    let messageObj = {};
    previewMessages.push(messageObj);

    messageObj.timeStamp = message.context.latestPost;
    messageObj.user = message.context.otherUsername;
    messageObj.picture = message.context.itemImageURL;
    promises.push(getItemsById([message.context.itemID]).then(itemInfo => {
        messageObj.title = itemInfo[Object.keys(itemInfo)[0]].title;
    }));
}
// Wait for them all to complete
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // use previewMessages
});
```

If they *have* to be in sequence, wait for each one before doing the next:

```
let previewMessages = [];
let promise = Promise.resolve();

// Loop through building up the `then` chain
for (let messageID in messages) {
    let message = messages[messageID];
    let messageObj = {};
    previewMessages.push(messageObj);

    // This one will wait for the next
    promise = promise.then(() => {
        messageObj.timeStamp = message.context.latestPost;
        messageObj.user = message.context.otherUsername;
        messageObj.picture = message.context.itemImageURL;
        return getItemsById([message.context.itemID]).then(itemInfo => {
            messageObj.title = itemInfo[Object.keys(itemInfo)[0]].title;
        });
    });
}
// Wait for the last one to complete
promise.then(() => {
    // Use previewMessages
});
```

---

But I'd probably make use of the literal to fill in the values we don't have to wait for:

Async:

```
let previewMessages = [];
let promises = [];

// Build the array of promises
for (let messageID in messages) {
    let message = messages[messageID];
    let messageObj = {
        timeStamp: message.context.latestPost,
        user: message.context.otherUsername,
        picture: message.context.itemImageURL
    };
    previewMessages.push(messageObj);

    promises.push(getItemsById([message.context.itemID]).then(itemInfo => {
        messageObj.title = itemInfo[Object.keys(itemInfo)[0]].title;
    }));
}
// Wait for them all to complete
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // use previewMessages
});
```

Sync:

```
let previewMessages = [];
let promise = Promise.resolve();

// Loop through building up the `then` chain
for (let messageID in messages) {
    let message = messages[messageID];
    let messageObj = {
        timeStamp: message.context.latestPost,
        user: message.context.otherUsername,
        picture: message.context.itemImageURL
    };
    previewMessages.push(messageObj);
    // This one will wait for the next
    promise = promise.then(() => {
        return getItemsById([message.context.itemID]).then(itemInfo => {
            messageObj.title = itemInfo[Object.keys(itemInfo)[0]].title;
        });
    });
}
// Wait for the last one to complete
promise.then(() => {
    // Use previewMessages
});
```

---

Maybe a pair of simplified, runnable examples would help. Also, you've mentioned that *"...the problem is that func2 takes the return object from func1..."* so let's add that into the mix.

Parallel:

```js
const messages = {
    "one": {name: "Message one"},
    "two": {name: "Message two"},
    "three": {name: "Message three"},
    "four": {name: "Message four"}
};

let previewMessages = [];
let promises = [];

// Build the array of promises
for (let messageID in messages) {
    let message = messages[messageID];
    let messageObj = {
        name: message.name
    };
    previewMessages.push(messageObj);

    promises.push(func1(message).then(func2).then(info => {
        messageObj.info = info;
    }));
}
// Wait for them all to complete
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // use previewMessages
    console.log("Done! Result:", previewMessages);
});

function func1(message) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Use setTimeout for async
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("func1 resolving on " + message.name);
            resolve(message.name + " - func1");
        }, Math.random() * 500);
    });
}
function func2(info) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Use setTimeout for async
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("func2 resolving on " + info);
            resolve(info +  " - func2");
        }, Math.random() * 500);
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Sequence:

```js
const messages = {
    "one": {name: "Message one"},
    "two": {name: "Message two"},
    "three": {name: "Message three"},
    "four": {name: "Message four"}
};

let previewMessages = [];
let promise = Promise.resolve();

// Build the promise chain
for (let messageID in messages) {
    let message = messages[messageID];
    let messageObj = {
        name: message.name
    };
    previewMessages.push(messageObj);

    promise = promise.then(() => func1(message).then(func2).then(info => {
        messageObj.info = info;
    }));
}
// Wait for the last one to finish
promise.then(() => {
    // use previewMessages
    console.log("Done! Result:", previewMessages);
});

function func1(message) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Use setTimeout for async
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("func1 resolving on " + message.name);
            resolve(message.name + " - func1");
        }, Math.random() * 500);
    });
}
function func2(info) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Use setTimeout for async
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("func2 resolving on " + info);
            resolve(info +  " - func2");
        }, Math.random() * 500);
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Would it be bad practice to just wrap the for loop in a closure? so it would be like: (function(i) {//for loop here})(messageID). This works but seems smelly

Comment: @VDog: What purpose would it serve? What, specifically, seems "smelly," and why?

Comment: Well, wrapping the closure waits for the loop to complete before running code outside of the loop. It seems smelly because it feels hacky. But it's working, no longer returning undefined. Also would you mind explaining your code, regarding the promises.push()? Does it push a series of promises to a variable promise, and once each promise in that array finish, it will run code in promise.then()?

Comment: @VDog: *"Well, wrapping the closure waits for the loop to complete before running code outside of the loop."* No, it doesn't. Wrapping something in an IIFE does nothing to change the timing of when it runs. Re pushing a promise on `promises`: It...pushes a promise on the array. As the code comment says, we build an array of the promises. Then we wait for all of those promises to complete. In the second version, `person =- person.then(...)`, we're scheduling the next async call to start when the previous promise completes. Standard promise chaining.

Comment: That makes sense got it. Thank you!